# ¿Comó se puede reproducir un video automatico pero con su audio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, jquery-ui

alguien de ustedes sabe si se puede realizar esa acción de que se reproduzca el video automático pero que se escuche, ya que investigando vi que se podía hacer con muted="muted" y vi que se puede hacer con muted="false" pero no me sirvio hay alguna manera para que se escuche, como en javascript o jquery, si alguien ya lo ha echo me podria auxiliar con eso.
Les dejo mi código.

```js
/*FUNCION PARA REPRODUCIR EL VIDEO=============================================================*/
function iniciarVideo(e) {

  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  if(video.paused){
    video.play();
     $(e).html("<i class='bx bx-pause-circle'></i>");
  }
  else{
    video.pause();
    $(e).html("<i class='bx bx-play-circle'></i>");
  }
}
/*=============================================================================================*/
```

```css
div.video {
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 40%;
    float: right;
  }

  div.video button {
    background: #000;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 80px;
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  div.video button:hover { background: #4B4949; }
```

```html
<div class="video">
      <video id="video" width="525" height="375" src="video/salirconvida.mp4" autoplay="true" muted="muted"></video>
      <button class="btnBuscarContrato repVideo" onclick="iniciarVideo(this);"><i class='bx bx-pause-circle'></i></button>
    </div>
```

Comment: En realidad para un muted lo haces con javascript, si quieres reproducirlo con el audio desde html quitale el muted, cuando esta etiqueta se encuentra presente, automaticamente desactiva el audio. Si no te funciona puedes probar con javascript directamente con ` var video = document.querySelector('video'); video.muted = false; video.play(); `

Answer (score 0):

Con el atributo `autoplay` de la etiqueta `video` puedes auto reproducirlo

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
<video autoplay>
  <source src="tuvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Tu navegador no soporta la reproducción de videos.
</video>
```

Con eso te debería de reproducir el audio.

Aquí te dejo un link con más información acerca de esto. https://www.anerbarrena.com/atributo-autoplay-html5-video-audio-5305/

Comment: Creo que esto no reproduce el vídeo con audio

Comment: A mi si me funciona, lo acabo de corroborar

Answer (score 0):

Algunos navegadores inhabilitan la reproducción automática de audio, porque puede ser molesto para el usuario abrir un sitio y que empiece a sonar. Puedes arreglar eso (al menos en Firefox) si la reproducción se inicia tras un clic del usuario (puede ser en otro elemento, siempre y cuando este invoque la reproducción). Por ejemplo: puedes poner que haya un botón de "Ingresar al sitio" y que, al pulsarlo se inicie la reproducción.

Answer (score 0):

No hay Forma de hacerlo, solo se puede hacer despues que el usuario da click en la pagina.
la siguiente es una forma que cree, poco traumatica pero necesitando de la ayuda de un modal para  obligar al usuario a dar click, pero solo la primera vez que ingresa, porque de alli en adelante desde que navegue por la web se podra reporducir el audio

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  try {
 $("#video_inicial")[0].play().catch(error => {
          $("#modal_play").modal("show");
        })
       } catch (error) {
        $("#modal_play").modal("show");
 console.log(error);
 }  

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Video Autoload</h2>
    <video id="video_inicial" width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
    
    <div id="modal_play" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" onclick='$("#video_inicial")[0].play()' class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"  onclick='$("#video_inicial")[0].play()' >Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

**esto solo ocurrira una sola vez**